# Toggle the css style of body of an html page

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I have a [sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/nwL67ao4/) where i am trying to toggle the css styles of body using jquery as,

```
 $('body').toggle( function () {
        (this).css('padding-top', '0px');
        (this).css('background-color', 'green');
    },
        function() {
        (this).css('padding-top', '50px');
        (this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
       });
```

But when I click on button the body completely disappears. How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using toggleClass instead

http://jsfiddle.net/nwL67ao4/1/

CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.hide {
    padding-top: 0px;
    background-color: green;    
}
```

JS:

```
$('button').click(function() {    
    $('body').toggleClass("hide");
});
```

HTML:

```
<button>ABCD</button>
```

Comment: Just a note: `.toggle()` was deprecated in 1.8 and removed from version 1.9

Comment: @GibboK I'm glad that you have mentioned that `.toggle()` event handler (not `.toggle()` for switching show/hide) is deprecated, +1.